# d3 v4 force layout tick function

Tags: d3.js

I'am trying to implement this [force directed tree](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1138500) layout. However, I am using d3 v4 instead of v3 and the `e` parameter does not get passed to the `tick` function in v4.

What would be the equivalent of `e.alpha` in v4?

```
function tick(e) {
    var k = 6 * e.alpha; // e is undefined in v4

    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let simulation = d3.forceSimulation()

...    

function ticked() {
    let k = 6 * simulation.alpha();

    ...
}
```

or

```
function ticked() {
    let k = 6 * this.alpha();

    ...
}
```

Comment: No need for a closure. You can use `this.alpha()`.